# iPhone 4S with GPS and GLONASS receiver

Tags: iphone, gps

I have a little understanding of GLONASS receiver and together with GPS, it's more accurate than the phones equipped only with A-GPS.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sf08o_j68XA) you have a video which compares A-GPS only iPhone 4 with iPhone 4S that has A-GPS+GLONASS. My question is, if I buy an iPhone 4S (as iPhone 5 Maps in India is next to useless), will I be able to see my current location on an offline map if both these receivers are present? (say for example CityMapsToGo)

Nokia is claiming the same with its Lumia 820 and 920, as it is equipped with both GPS and GLONASS receivers.

["These two smartphones also include autonomous assisted GPS and GLONASS receivers. In plain English, this means that you can see yourself on a map within seconds, even when you’re offline."](http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/09/06/nokia-maps-for-windows-phone-8-goes-offline/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS and GLONASS are almost the same things, one operated from the USA and the other from Russia, respectively. The differences are too technical for this question and I won’t get into them.

Also, if your new iPhone 4S ships with iOS 6, you won’t be able to downgrade to iOS 5.

And yes, you can see your location in offline maps.

Comment: thank you very much for that answer! I didn't know iPhone 4S ships with iOS6 :-(.. Guess I have to install that Maps+ app if I purchase one.. if possible, can you give a link to any article which explains the technical differences, how a person can see his/her location offline when both receivers are installed etc...

Comment: There’s no article which actually explains the technical differences, but you can learn more about that by reading the respective Wikipedia articles. And there’s no “how-to” guide to viewing your location offline. It just works.